# Does SAS server disks rotate always in it's default speed (like 10K, 15K)

Tags: performance, hard-drive, hardware, sas

I have some concerns about disk throughput in order to plan my SQL Server deployment. I know from experience that consumer SATA disks sometimes go into sleep mode when not used for a longer period. Do SAS server drives always rotate at default speed (like 10K, 15K) ? So they maintain maximum speed all the time but also consume more energy all the time.

Comment: Note that you can control this behavior on consumer-grade drives using `hdparm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, enterprise SAS disks spin at a fixed rotation speed.

They will not go into power or energy-saving modes like certain consumer drives.